# How should I avoid stubbing properties with Sinon.js

Tags: javascript, sinon

I've discovered that Sinon doesn't let you stub properties, only methods. I'm trying to figure out how to deal with/embrace this.

I have the following code:

```
var Player = {
  addPoints: function(points) {
    this.score += points;
  },
  score: 0
}

var Game = {
  setPlayers: function(players) {
    this.players = players;
  },
  over: function() {
    return this.players.some(function(player) {
      return player.score >= 100;
    });
  },
}
```

Here's a test I wrote:

```
describe("Game", function() {
  it("is over if a player has at least 100 points", function() {
    var game = Object.create(Game);
    player = Object.create(Player);
    game.setPlayers([player]);
    player.addPoints(100);
    game.over().should.be.true;
  });
});
```

It feels wrong to me to have to go in and call `addPoints()` on `Player` when I'm testing `Game`. My initial instinct was to stub `Player.points`, but I can't do so, because Sinon only stubs properties, not methods.

How should I be thinking about this?

Answer (score 9):

I emailed the SinonJS mailing list, and the author wrote back:

> Exactly like you have done. Directly writing to the score property 
>   completely defeats the purpose of the addPoints method, and makes your
>   test tightly coupled to the implementation (thus making it brittle).
>
> If you really do want to "stub" the property, here's how:

```
describe("Game", function() {
  it("is over if a player has at least 100 points", function() { 
    var game = Object.create(Game); 
    player = Object.create(Player); 
    game.setPlayers([player]); 
    player.score = 100; 
    game.over().should.be.true;
  });
});
```

> It's a property on an instance - no point in being too clever about
>   it.  I still recommend you don't do it this way though.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to stub `game.points` just set it. So you can create a simple mock for `Game`, which is just an `object` holding a spy for the `setPlayer` method. and then you can set `score` in the test to what ever you want.

```
describe("Game", function() {
  var game;

  before(function(){
    game = {addPoints: jasmine.createSpy()}
  })

  it("is over if a player has at least 100 points", function() { 
    game.score = 100;
    player = Object.create(Player);
    game.setPlayers([player]);
    game.over().should.be.true;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - that seems obvious in retrospect.